# How to improve polymorphism with design patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm attempting to design a system that will allow the processing of multiple types of file. The idea being that there's a single application to handle the actual manipulation of the files on disk, while developers can write custom libraries that will be able to do whatever they want with the files once loaded.

I current have a structure that looks like this:

[Original Image](http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1179/5144976247_4cb92529a1_b.jpg)
[image: current class diagram]

Where the application publishes an `IClient` interface that the custom written libraries are free to implement. `Client1` to `Client3` would each have a different implementation and respond to each type of file in a different way.

The `Populate` method on `File` is overriden in the derived classes to call the correct `PopulateFrom` method on the `IClient` interface, passing in the calling file.

Therefore the `PopulateFrom` method on the class implementing `IClient` is passed a file of a specific type so that it has to access the underlying data (`CSVDataReader` or `XDocument` in this example) to parse into whatever domain-specific objects it wants.

Using this design for every new type of file I add to the system I would have to add a new method to `IClient` which isn't ideal. To preserve compatibility with the client classes that don't have the method accepting the new file type I'm going to have to create a new interface that specifically supports that type and have the new client implement that:

[Original Image](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4111/5145576518_d75c77fc03_b.jpg)
[image: class diagram with new file type]

That all works, but I was wondering whether there's a better way of supporting the multiple file types without having to add a new interface every time, possibly using a design pattern?

Comment: Could you please add links to the higher resolution images? There are almost unreadable.

Comment: I've updated with links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option: your `PopulateFrom` method should not take a specific file type, instead it should take a `FileStream` or `MemoryStream`, after all a file is simply a stream of bytes, it is the organisation of those bytes that makes each file type unique.

Additionally, you may want to implement a method similar to this:

```
bool CanProcess(FileStream myFile)
```

that way you can query each provider in a generic way and it will tell you if it can process that particular file. Doing it this way will allow you to implement more file types and more providers without having to extend your interface or mess with the existing providers.

Check out the [Provider pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model) to see if it helps.

Comment: Oh, now that's an interesting thought... I can push the memory stream up to file, have the derived classes provide data for it in their own way and, like you say let, let the client figure how, or even if, it can process it. I'll have a look into the Provider pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your design violates the design principle known as Dependency inversion, because clients depend on concrete classes instead of abstract ones.

You should reconsider implementing your clients in a way they work with the abstract type (Application::File). If there's absolutely no way to do that, then you should redesign the class hierarchy.

Think about it. If an abstraction is seldom used then it is probably useless. Robert Martin terms this as the Stable abstractions principle.

Comment: That's kinda the problem I'm having and trying to solve though, that I need the data from the concrete classes (as it could be *anything*) but I want to improve the way the abstraction works. Also, the abstraction to File isn't used heavily here, but this is a small snapshot of the overall system, it's used more elsewhere.

Comment: Well, maybe then CVSFile, XMLFile, etc should hold a File instead of inheriting File. In any case, I believe you should focus on cohesion between the clients (what makes them similar?). If there's no cohesion - then the clients should use disjoint interfaces. If there is cohesion, it should be expressed somehow, e.g. by an additional class. HTH